# List vs. listing

Tags: word-usage

I'm developing an e-commerce software that deals with products and categories. Can I use the term **"category listing"** for a list of products in a given category? Or does "category listing" strictly mean a single item in a list of categories, i.e., something different than I'm hoping for?

I know a perfectly fine term is "product list" (e.g., `productList` as a variable name), the only downside is that it's quite generic in an online store, for example, a search returns a list of products, the homepage renders a list of products, etc. Is there a suitable term that would start with the word "category" by any chance?

Comment: Are you looking for a client-facing term (one visible in a UI), or just something you'd use on the backend (e.g. as a variable name)?

Comment: A variable name. I still feel that `categoryListing` is technically incorrect – that it means something different than a list of products in a category. Or doesn't it?

Comment: Given that you don't mind `productList` for products, what's wrong with `categoryList` for categories?

Comment: @JasonBassford That's a list of categories, like category A, category B, etc. I need a term for a list of products within a single category.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question. It starts off with "I'm developing an e-commerce software that deals with **products** and **categories**." Are you actually dealing with a  piece of e-commerce software that deals with several products but only one category?

Comment: The question in the OP is "Can I use the term *category listing* for a list of products in a given category?". Sorry if the first sentence is confusing (all e-commerce solutions deal with multiple products and multiple categories; that doesn't change my main question though).